# How to verify if $\operatorname{corr}(X,Y)=\operatorname{corr}(log(X),log(Y))$?

Tags: statistics, regression, variance, covariance, correlation

I am totally blind to this verification, is this true?

$\operatorname{corr}(X,Y)=\operatorname{corr}(log(X),log(Y))$

$$
\operatorname{corr}(X,Y)=\frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)}{\operatorname{var}(X)\operatorname{var}(Y)}\\
\operatorname{corr}(ln(X),ln(Y))=\frac{\operatorname{cov}(ln(X),ln(Y))}{\operatorname{var}(ln(X))\operatorname{var}(ln(Y))}
$$

Thank you for any comments

Even writing out the definition of each, I have no idea how to compare them.

Comment: I don't see any reason for this to be true. Where does the question come from?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I was doing Eview programming and run a generalised-$R^2$ which when we have a log-linear model. By formula, the generalised-$R^2=(corr(y,\hat{y}))^2$. The tutor shows this in Eveiw by run $corr(log(y),log(\hat{y}))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a claim cannot possibly be true; e.g., if $\Pr[X < 0] > 0$ or $\Pr[Y < 0] > 0$, the RHS is undefined but the LHS still exists.

Even if you restrict the support of $X$ and $Y$ to be positive, then even a simple location-transformed Bernoulli example will show otherwise; e.g.,
$$\Pr[(X,Y) = (1,1)] = 1/6 \\
\Pr[(X,Y) = (2,1)] = 1/3 \\
\Pr[(X,Y) = (1,4)] = 1/8 \\
\Pr[(X,Y) = (2,4)] = 3/8$$
gives $$\rho_{XY} = \frac{25}{3\sqrt{383}}$$ but
$$\rho_{\log X \log Y} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{429}}.$$